Ubuntu Loading and Scroll Issue
I have Lenovo X390 Yoga. I installed Ubuntu 24.04.1 and before the OS loads I see a pattern of letters and numbers as attached, which is versy strange. Another issue is that after a period of usage, the mouse refuses to scroll down and any instance of scroll down goes back up and refuses to scrol down on mouse until I use the down button on keybopord. What could the cause of the two issues and what's the solution?
